# is this sentence using ほど　grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

I was watching this youtube vidoe about making a dish out of an greater amberjack fish (kampachi) and the cook
said this:

> 鰤ほどは痛むスピードが遅いですけど

i think he wants to say that the greater amberjack fish spoils slower than the 鰤 fish but if that was the case should not he have said 早くない instead ?
https://youtu.be/r8peOCisk94?t=420

Comment: I think he might have wanted to say something like 鰤ほど早く痛まないんですけど or 鰤より痛むスピードが遅いんですけど　but ended up combining the sentences together in a weird way. It sounds to me like he wants to say that "カンパチ" spoils slower than "鰤" but still spoils pretty fast but I could be wrong. By the way I love Kimagure Cook. I learned a bunch of fish related vocabulary from his videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 99.9% sure he meant to say `鰤ほどは痛むスピードが速くないですけど`. `鰤ほどは痛むスピードが遅いですけど` is not grammatical (so I'm 100% he misspoke).